# Reusing nested classes in LESS for sprite icon reuse

Tags: css, less, css-sprites, nested-class

I have a `.less` file that contains classes to manage my sprites, such as:

```
.icon-16 { 
    background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-16.png') no-repeat top left; 
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;  

    &.about { background-position: 0px 0px;  } 
    &.add { background-position: 0px -16px;  } 
    &.add2 { background-position: 0px -32px;  }
}
```

Later on in another `.less` file that is being linked, I need to set background images using these sprites.

I know it is possible to reuse a class like this:

```
.myClass {
  .mySharedClass;
}
```

However I'm unable to work out the correct syntax to reuse a class in a nested hierarchy.

What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
.myClass {
  .icon-16.about;
}
```

Giving the following output (from **both** `.icon-16` and `.about`):

```
.myClass {
    background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-16.png') no-repeat top left; 
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
```

However this doesn't compile.

1. How can I achieve this nested class reuse?
2. If what I'm trying to do is not possible, what would be the best alternative to allow my
   sprites to be used in other classes?

Comment: did you try `.icon-16 .about`?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to reuse `.icon-16.about` as a mixin in a class ? The only cases I see would make more sense with a direct class like `.icon_about`.

Comment: You must be using an old version of LESS, because version 1.3.2+ compiles your code correctly on [this compiler](http://less2css.org/). When you say you want background images applied, does that mean you want to reuse the core part of `.icon-16` (image path and dimensions) plus the particular positioning of the `.about` addition?

Comment: @ScottS Yes exactly that. I've updated my question to show the desired output. I'm currently using the less support in Visual Studio 2012.2. The only information I can find is that Web Essentials was downgraded to 1.3.1 on Jan 21st 2013. I'm unsure if it's been bumped since the release of VS2012.2 tooling update.

Comment: @dystroy The first class specifies the url for the sprite, the subsequent class defines the position of the desired image. If I had dedicated classes for each there would be a lot of duplication of the sprite url. Here is the sprite generator I have used which generates this css convention [InstantSprite](http://instantsprite.com/)

Comment: @ScottS I have tested that compiler and yes it correctly targets the nested class when doing .icon-16.about;. However I'm unable to include the parent classes css without it generating rules for all nested classes too.

Comment: Do you have control of modifying the `.icon-16` defining code?

Comment: @ScottS Yes. However I do not have control over the markup/class generation which is why I cannot just apply the sprite classes to the markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Specific Solution in This Case

I recommend making a master mixin to generate what you need, as you need it. Here is a solution that works with your current version of LESS 1.3.1:

**LESS**

```
.make-icon-16(@form: all) { 
    background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-16.png') no-repeat top left; 
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;

    @about: 0px 0px;
    @add: 0px -16px;
    @add2: 0px -32px;

    .makePositioning() when (@form = all) {
      &.about { background-position: @about;  } 
      &.add { background-position: @add;  } 
      &.add2 { background-position: @add2;  }
    }

    .makePositioning() when (@form = about) {
      background-position: @about;  
    } 
    .makePositioning() when (@form = add) {
      background-position: @add;  
    }
    .makePositioning() when (@form = add2) {
      background-position: @about;  
    } 

    .makePositioning();  
}

//to generate icon classes
.icon-16 {
  .make-icon-16;
}

//to include as you want in your class
.myClass {
  .make-icon-16(about);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.icon-16 {
  background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-16.png') no-repeat top left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.icon-16.about {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.icon-16.add {
  background-position: 0px -16px;
}
.icon-16.add2 {
  background-position: 0px -32px;
}
.myClass {
  background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-16.png') no-repeat top left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

If you don't need or want the actual `.icon-16` classes, skip the step that makes those as it is not necessary for you to do that.

### More General Solution?

***If your icons have the right logic to them***, then this can be more generalized to accommodate any size icon.

**LESS**

```
.make-icon(@form: all, @size: 16) { 
    background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-@{size}.png') no-repeat top left; 
    width: @size*1px; 
    height: @size*1px;

    @about: 0px 0px;
    @add: 0px (@size*-1px);
    @add2: 0px (@size*-2px);

    .makePositioning() when (@form = all) {
      &.about { background-position: @about;  } 
      &.add { background-position: @add;  } 
      &.add2 { background-position: @add2;  }
    }

    .makePositioning() when (@form = about) {
      background-position: @about;  
    } 
    .makePositioning() when (@form = add) {
      background-position: @add;  
    }
    .makePositioning() when (@form = add2) {
      background-position: @about;  
    } 

    .makePositioning();  
}

//to generate icon classes for 32px size
.icon-32 {
  .make-icon(all, 32);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.icon-32 {
  background: url('/Content/images/app/icons-32.png') no-repeat top left;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-32.about {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.icon-32.add {
  background-position: 0px -32px;
}
.icon-32.add2 {
  background-position: 0px -64px;
}
```

Comment: This is great! I will however need to come up with a solution to translate the css that the sprite generator produces into this. But thanks for showing me the way!

Comment: @Poz: So if the files are always named `icons-##` where `##` is the pixel size of the icons, and the shifts always occur in the background position as originally noted, then the general solution allows you to reuse the same code to make code for any size icon in any class you want.

Comment: What I meant by that was if we need to rebuild the sprite, we wouldn't want to manually update all of the hardcoded parts of the master mixin. But I'm sure we can come up with a separate solution to automate that.